# python - tkinter , sistema de ventas

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas , dejo aca las dos funciones , la primera es para agregar la venta que se ingresa a una tabla y la otra es para generar la venta en la base de datos , estoy muy trabado en esto y no puedo continuar , me gustaria ver aunquesea de poner un error para que al querer ingresar un elemento ya cargado no me deje pero tampoco pude hacerlo funcionar

el problema es que al cargar por ejemplo:

1 - caramelo $5....
2 - chicle $3....
1 - caramelo $5

en la base de datos solo se me descuenta del stock 1 caramelo y no 2 , aunque en la muestra del total la cuenta de: $13
en la **base de datos** :  si tengo 10 caramelos me aparecen 9 y no 8

-------- FUNCION DE ADD VENTA ---------

```
def add_vta(self,*args,**kwargs):
        try:    
            self.cantidad_valor = int(self.cantidad_a.get())
            if self.cantidad_valor > int(self.obtener_stock):
                self.msj = messagebox.showinfo("Error","La cantidad deseada supera el stock disponible.")

            else:
                self.precio_final = (float(self.cantidad_valor) * float(self.obtener_precio)) - (float(self.descuento_a.get()))
                lista_producto.append(self.obtener_nombre)
                precio_product.append(self.precio_final)
                cantidad_producto.append(self.cantidad_valor)
                id_producto.append(self.obtener_id)
                precio_Unitario.append(self.obtener_precio)
                self.contador = 0

                #Limpiando tabla
                records = self.tablax.get_children()
                for element in records:
                    self.tablax.delete(element)

            for self.p in lista_producto:

                self.tablax.insert('',10, text=(str(id_producto[self.contador])), values=(str(lista_producto[self.contador]), str(cantidad_producto[self.contador]), str(precio_Unitario[self.contador]), str(precio_product[self.contador])))
                self.contador+=1  

                # configuracion total 
                self.tota1.configure(text="Total:      $" + str(sum(precio_product)))
                #Eliminar
                self.cantidad1.place_forget()
                self.cantidad_a.place_forget()
                self.descuento1.place_forget()
                self.descuento_a.place_forget()
                self.nombre_producto.configure(text="")
                self.precio_producto.configure(text="")
                self.agregar_venta.place_forget()
                # autofocus en ingreso de id
                self.ingresar_id.focus()
                self.ingresar_id.delete(0, END) 

        except:
            messagebox.showinfo("Cuidado", "Debe Ingresar La Cantidad Deseada")
```

------------- FUNCION DE GENERAR VENTA EN BASE DE DATOS -------------

```
def generar_factura_ajax(self,*args,**kwargs):
        # Crear factura de venta unica
        self.x= 0
        inicio = " SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE id =? "
        result= self.ejecuta_consulta(inicio, (id_producto[self.x], ))
        for i in lista_producto:
            for r in result:
                self.stock_antiguo= r[2]
                self.nuevo_stock = int(self.stock_antiguo) - int(cantidad_producto[self.x])
            #actualizando stock
            sql = "UPDATE Productos SET stock=? WHERE id=?"
            self.ejecuta_consulta(sql, (self.nuevo_stock, id_producto[self.x]))

            # insertar en BD transaccion
            sql2 = "INSERT INTO Transacciones (nombre, stock, monto, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
            self.ejecuta_consulta(sql2, (lista_producto[self.x], cantidad_producto[self.x], precio_product[self.x], date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S')))
            self.x +=1

        #Limpiando tabla
        records = self.tablax.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tablax.delete(element)

        for a in labels_listas:
            a.destroy()    

        del(lista_producto[:])
        del(id_producto[:])
        del(cantidad_producto[:])
        del(precio_product[:])  

        self.tota1.configure(text="")
        self.paga_con.configure(text="")
        self.paga_con1.place_forget() 
        self.descuento_a.delete(0, END)
        self.ingresar_id.focus() 
        self.pagac_btn.place_forget()
        self.vuelto.place_forget()
        self.vuelto1.place_forget()

        messagebox.showinfo("Perfecto", "Venta realizada con exito")
```

Comment: No hace falta colocar en el título la palabra solución, con marcar tu respuesta como aceptada alcanza

Answer (score 1):

Solución del problema : Re formular la lógica en la consulta

```
 def generar_factura_ajax(self,*args,**kwargs):
    # Crear factura de venta unica
    self.x= 0
    for i in lista_producto:
        #actualizando stock
        sql = "UPDATE Productos SET stock=stock-? WHERE id=?"
        self.ejecuta_consulta(sql, (cantidad_producto[self.x], id_producto[self.x]))

        # insertar en BD transaccion
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO Transacciones (nombre, stock, monto, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
        self.ejecuta_consulta(sql2, (lista_producto[self.x], cantidad_producto[self.x], precio_product[self.x], date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S')))
        self.x +=1

    #Limpiando tabla
    records = self.tablax.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tablax.delete(element)  

    del(lista_producto[:])
    del(id_producto[:])
    del(cantidad_producto[:])
    del(precio_product[:])  

    self.tota1.configure(text="")
    self.paga_con.configure(text="")
    self.paga_con1.place_forget() 
    self.descuento_a.delete(0, END)
    self.ingresar_id.focus() 
    self.pagac_btn.place_forget()
    self.vuelto.place_forget()
    self.vuelto1.place_forget()

    messagebox.showinfo("Perfecto", "Venta realizada con exito")
```

Comment: Añade como y porque